# How to create connection between MySQL table to query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I wrote the query for inserting data to MySQL table "Persons":

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
try
{         
    String insert = "INSERT INTO Persons (id,Name,Surname,Address,Phone) VALUES ('" + txtId.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtSurname.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "')";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert,con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Id is not valid");
}
```

But it's not working. I have one connection for the whole database, but it's not working for a specific table. How I can create a connection between specific table to query in C#?

Comment: Where are you defining your connection params? What's the error?

Comment: public Form1()
        {
           con.ConnectionString = @"data source=LENOVO-UZBEKSEV\SQLEXPRESS...............................................
        }

Comment: When i open the server Explorer, none table in dataConnection, but i have two tables in MySQL database: Persons,Actions

Comment: where you use **connection_string** in sql connection

Answer (score 0):

What is it?    `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()` you need to pass a connection string which comprises DBname, username, pasword, server name ... etc; you are not passing those information anywhere then how can you expect it to connect to your database without having the information.

Pass the connection string either in constructor or using the property.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string)
```

(OR)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = connection_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to insert data into the tables. I suggest to use parametrized sql query to keep safe from malicious occurrence.

Firstly you should have a `ConnectionString` something like this:

```
string connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;User ID=UserName;Password=YourPassword;Server=ServerName";
```

And than:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, ColN) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @ColN)");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", txtPhone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColN", txtAddress.Text);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Please edit your credentials before trying.
Replace `localhost` with SQL server instance name, `user id` with your MySQL server instance user id, `password` with your MySQL server instance password and `testdb` with your database name. It should work fine.

```
string connectionString = @"server=localhost;user id=admin;password=admin;database=testdb;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{         
    String insert = "INSERT INTO Persons (id,Name,Surname,Address,Phone) VALUES ('" + txtId.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtSurname.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtPhone.Text + "')";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert,con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Id is not valid");
}
```

Comment: I have a connection to Data Base, it works when I run code, in my gridView i see my table from Sql with all parameters. The problem that i cant  insert new data or update.